# How to validate text field using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate text field using javascript. `return false` is working fine. but `return true` is not working.

HTML

```
<form namme="frms" action="booking_management.php">
    <input type="text" name="total" id="totald" value="" onkeyup="calbill()" class="input"/>
    <input name="but" type="button" value="Send Bill" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="bill()" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function bill() {
  if (Checktot()) {
    document.forms["frms"].submit();
  }
}

function Checktot() {
  var tot = document.getElementById("totald").value;
  if (tot == "no") {
    document.getElementById("totald").style.borderColor = "#ED291F";
    alert("Please try again");
    return false;
  }
  return true;

}
```

Comment: better use jquery validate plugin. see this link http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Comment: You have typo: `namme="frms"`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined

```
document.forms["frms"].submit();
```

[ERROR DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5r5m4wkj/)

---

You can use this:

```
document.forms[0].submit()
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5r5m4wkj/1/)